# Springboot using @Autowired on constructor with parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm using springboot 1.3.8 and I have a `@Autowired` on a constructor with parameters but I get the error: No default constructor found...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App implements CommandLineRunner {

  private ApplicationContext context;
  private CLIHelper cliHelper;

  @Autowired
  public App(ApplicationContext context, CLIHelper cliHelper) {
    this.context = context;
    this.cliHelper = cliHelper;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
  }
}
```

Comment: Answer is in your message. No default constructor i.e. public App() {...} available. Why don't you use @Autowired on fields?

Comment: Is CLIhelper is a bean?

Comment: Yes, CLIhelper is a bean, it´s anotated as @Component

Comment: Irother, I´d like to have a constructor with parameter to test some functionality. Some like this:                                                                            Autowired                                                                                       private ApplicationContext context;                                                                        Autowired
private CLIHelper cliHelper;                                                                           App app= new App(context, cliHelper);                                                      app.someMethods()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your class is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` which is also `@Configuration`. And `@Configuration` should have a default no-args constructor.
From [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.M2/api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html):

> @Configuration classes must have a default/no-arg constructor and may
>   not use @Autowired constructor parameters.

Since Spring version 4.3 you can have constructor injection for `@Configuration` class. Tested on Spring Boot version 1.5.3 and it works fine.

[Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-4.3.html) are the release notes for Spring 4.3. And here is the feature that you need:

> @Configuration classes support constructor injection.